# How to get last processed block info from local baker node and save all processed blocks information into a database using Jakarta test blockchain?

Tags: baker

I have created a local baker node and run tezos using "./tezos-node run" command. Now I want to store all blocks information into a database and show it to my website. Please help me with it. Thanking you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Technical answer:**

You have to:

- fetch successive blocks with RPC `/chains/main/blocks/<head|block_hash>`
- process new blocks on the fly, and eventually get back until the genesis block
- store the blocks' data in a DB at your convenience
- handle the case where the (one of the) latest fetch blocks (cf. Tenderbake finality) should be reverted because another one has been finalized

This part is what is called an (a blockchain) indexer. Then you should expose the content of your database via an API server.

**Non-technical answer/question:**

Why do want to do this? There are already indexers and block explorers on/for Tezos.

Comment: I want to show the last processed block on my website. I know it is already exists in TzStats.

Comment: I have a confusion. I am running the node using command line "./tezos-node run". I can see the blocks here but how to fetch data from here using RPC /chains/main/blocks/<head|block_hash>. Please let me know.

Comment: @MuhtasimFahim You send a HTTP GET request (or POST for other endpoints) to the full URL pointing to your server, with `/chains/main/blocks/<head|block_hash>` being the endpoint. E.g. `http://mydomain.com/chains/main/blocks/<head|block_hash>` or maybe an IP address / port number

Comment: I need to fetch the processed blocks automatically and store the data of those blocks into database and show only the last processed block information. Can you please give me any resource or tutorials how to go with it? It would be helpful and the API is also not working in my local device.

Comment: I can get it by ./tezos-client rpc get /chains/<chain_id>/blocks/<block_id>. How can I make the block_id or hash dynamic?

Comment: "not working" - this statement is not something anyone can help with. Please ALWAYS describe the issue (e.g. the code you tried, the error you received etc). If you need to provide more details, do so by editing your initial question. There are many resources online for helping users get up to speed with using the CLI or RPC, such as: https://opentezos.com/tezos-basics/cli-and-rpc/

Comment: @MuhtasimFahim as iguer already said, using the keyword `head` instead of a hash or id will always return whatever the latest block is

Comment: Sorry for not giving the right information. Now I can get the latest block info by "./tezos-client rpc get /chains/main/blocks/head". Thank you for helping me and now I have to fetch the data to my nodejs server. You can suggest me how to do it.

Comment: @MuhtasimFahim you have already been told how to do that for your node js server, you need to use the RPC. I've also sent you a link to a tutorial, please read the resources / answers you are being given

Comment: Thank you so much. Got it.

Comment: Sorry, I haven't gotten notifications for all replies. I suppose Simon helped you going forward.